# Amazon DynamoDb get a sorted list of entities

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Given the following recipe table:

---

### | ID | LAST_MODIFIED | OTHER_ATTRIBUTES          |

---

Saying that ID is the hash primary key, and given a list of recipe ids: **idList**. 
How is possible to retrieve the top ten most recently modified recipes entities, where the ID is contained into **idList**?

If is not possible with the current table structure, could someone help me find a better one?

I am currently developing using the AWS Java SDK.

In SQL it would be:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Recipes 
WHERE id IN (idList) 
ORDER BY last_modified LIMIT 10
```

Every help will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Avoid using statements such as "Hope someone more expert will be able to help me with this.", this does not add information to the question and increases the chance it will be voted down.

Comment: Nice, let me suggest another edit: Are you trying to accomplish this from the web management console, from the command line interface or from the SDK (Java, .NET,...)?

Comment: I think that the question is more related to the overall design of the table rather than the technology I am using. But thanks I will add these details.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on your table design.

The simplest option would be to make your recipe ID the range key.

> Query results are always sorted by the range key. If the data type of
>   the range key is Number, the results are returned in numeric order;
>   otherwise, the results are returned in order of ASCII character code
>   values. By default, the sort order is ascending. To reverse the order,
>   set the ScanIndexForward parameter to false.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryAndScan.html

Probably a better alternative would be to create a global secondary index on recipe id. An example with sorting is provided in the documentation at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html

Comment: Thanks, I changed a bit the question. Hopefully is more clear now.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to create a separate table "RecentModifiedRecipe" which contains the 10 most recently modified recipies.

Every time you modifiy a recipe in "idList", you need to

1) insert this recipe id into RecentModifiedRecipe table if it is not already there.

2) remove the oldest recipe id from RecentModifiedRecipe.